# Tao Analysis 1 proposition 4.3.7 (d)

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

I'm trying to prove proposition 4.3.7 part (d), which is: Let x,y,z,w be rational numbers.  Let $\epsilon, \delta > 0$.  If $|x-y| < \epsilon$ and $|z-w|<\delta$, then $|x+z|< \epsilon + \delta$, $|y+w|<\epsilon + \delta$, $|x-z|< \epsilon + \delta$, and $|y-w|< \epsilon + \delta$.

I tried to use the triangle inequality and I became stuck.  I'm unsure of where to go from there.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The statement you have written is not true; a counterexample is $\epsilon=\delta=1$ and $x=y = 0$ and $z=w = 100$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted statement is wrong, as noted already in a comment.

What *Proposition 4.3.7 (d)* actually states is:
[image]

The above translates to $\,\big|(x+z) - (y+w)\big| \lt \epsilon+\delta\,$, which follows from the triangle inequality:

$$\,\big|(x+z) - (y+w)\big| = \big|(x-y) + (z-w)\big| \le |x-y| + |z-w| \lt \epsilon+\delta\,$$